# Reliable way to kill AV processes on windows?

Tags: command-line, process, anti-virus

What is a reliable way to kill AV Processes that are protected against termination? (Like most antivirus)

I have SYSTEM level access on a machine but running a `taskkill /F` on the process still returns "Access Denied"

I've tried `wmic process where name='' delete`.. Still Access Denied.

Is there any way I can kill a process like this?

Comment: There is no single answer to this, it will depend on how the security product has implemented self defence.  I suspect that there is a driver preventing it. Given the vendor of the solution I assume they will have one or more drivers loaded that start early at boot.  Have you tried Process Hacker?  You might need one driver to take out another without booting into safe mode to potentially disable drivers.

Comment: @HelpingHand Wouldn't install process hacker require a reboot? 

It was for a penetration test, is installing a driver the only way to kill the AV? Also do you have any resources I can look into to learn more about how these defenses work?

Comment: The other would to just trigger the uninstall or unload of said application (again depends on the manufacturer and what he supports).